# How can I create a DateTime object from a string that is already in a specific timezone?

Tags: php, datetime

I am working within an environment (wordpress) in which all default timezone settings are set to UTC.

Within that, I want to create a timer function that deals with the time always in the local server time (+8).

The goal is to have a function that returns a DateTime object to any given date (input with a `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` format, always in the local +8 timezone

```
function datetime_obj($date = NULL) {
    $date_new = new DateTime($date);
    $date_new->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Hong_Kong'));
    return $date_new;
}
```

This works great when I try to get today's date/time information ($date = NULL). However if I have an existing time (in HKG time) as a string (say from a datetime field in a MySQL database), I cannot generate a new datetime object from it since it is treated as UTC. The resulting DateTime object from the function above has always added 8 hours to it.

How can I change the above function so that a $date that is inserted is accepted as already being in the correct +8 timezone and not changed +8 as an output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but the doc says:

```
public DateTime::__construct() ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )
```

> time: A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in Date and Time
> Formats. Enter NULL here to obtain the current time when using the
> $timezone parameter.
>
> timezone: A DateTimeZone object representing the timezone of $time. If
> $timezone is omitted, the current timezone will be used.
>
> Note: The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored
> when the $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800)
> or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

so... this:

```
$date_new = new DateTime($date."+08:00");
```

or this:

```
$date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Hong_Kong'));
```

should do the job